# Issue setting StackNavigation background color to transparent (shows white)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a react native applicaiton that I am currently building. One part of my react native application is that if the user is not logged in, I want to show a background image with the content from the LoginScreen displaying on the screen with a red background. I am noticing that the AuthenticationStackNavigation cards all have a white background for som reason and I can not remove it by setting `cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' },` I dont know how to remove the background. I also tried setting `backgroundColor: 'transparent'`. Does anyone know how to remove the background.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from '../Screens/Authentication/LoginScreen';
import SignupScreen from '../Screens/Authentication/SignupScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../Screens/Authentication/ProfileScreen';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from '../Screens/Authentication/ForgotPasswordScreen';
import ConfirmEmailScreen from '../Screens/Authentication/ConfirmEmailScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const AuthenticationStackNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNav.Navigator
        initialRouteName="LoginScreen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' },
        }}>
        <StackNav.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <StackNav.Screen name="SignupScreen" component={SignupScreen} />
        <StackNav.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <StackNav.Screen name="ForgotPasswordScreen" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <StackNav.Screen name="ConfirmEmailScreen" component={ConfirmEmailScreen} />
      </StackNav.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AuthenticationStackNavigation;
```

You can see the background image I have. The red login for is from the LoginScreen.tsx.

My issue is with the navigation.

[image: screen image from react native applicaiotn]

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom theme to set the background color transparent. Something like this:

```js
<ImageBackground
  source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/1080/1920' }}
  resizeMode="cover"
  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <NavigationContainer
    theme={{
      ...DefaultTheme,
      colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        background: 'transparent',
      },
    }}>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</ImageBackground>
```

See details how to use [Themes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/).